# Text widget crashes before it gets data from async function in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm in this course by London App Brewery. I'm making weather app, and a problem appears when function needs to update my UI with relevant weather data. I've done everything like tutor from the course, but it looks like something is changed since they made that app.

The function looks like this:

```
 WeatherModel weather = WeatherModel();
 int temperature;
 String weatherIcon;
 String weatherText;
 String cityName;

 @override
 void initState() {
     super.initState();
     updateUI(widget.locationWeather);
 }

 void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
     setState(() {
     double temp = weatherData["main"]["temp"] - 273.15;
     temperature = temp.toInt();
     int condition = weatherData["weather"][0]["id"];
     weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);
     cityName = weatherData["name"];
     weatherText = weather.getMessage(temperature);
   });
```

This is exactly the code from the course which should work, but it doesn't for me. Error appears saying it expects a future (updateUI function). So I did some research and updated the function like this:

```
void updateUI(Future<dynamic> locationWeather) async{
     var weatherData = await locationWeather;
     setState(() {
     double temp = weatherData["main"]["temp"] - 273.15;
     temperature = temp.toInt();
     int condition = weatherData["weather"][0]["id"];
     weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);
     cityName = weatherData["name"];
     weatherText = weather.getMessage(temperature);
   });
```

So like this I get it kinda working. Main screen where this data is shown, works. But a screen before that one, its where actual API call happens and it uses navigator to switch to main screen. It also shows loading spinner, while it gets data. So situation is, my loading screen is showing error about Text widgets being null and it switches to main screen where everything works as it should. I guess that because values in those text widgets are actually null since this function is called on main screen initState and not on loading screen.

EDIT:

locationWeather comes from Loading Screen class:

```
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
double latitude;
double longitude;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocationData();
}

void getLocationData() async {
   Location location = Location();
   await location.getCurrentLocation();

   NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
   lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&appid=$apiKey");
   var weatherData = networkHelper.getData();

   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return LocationScreen(weatherData);  // this is locationWeather
  }));
 }
```

Comment: have you tried "Future updateUI(locationWeather) async{" ?

Comment: How did you declared, set `locationWeather` and what value it contains ?

Comment: @Adnankarim no difference. Error happens on loading screen and app proceeds to main screen. I/flutter (29276): A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
I/flutter (29276): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
I/flutter (29276): Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'

Comment: @MidhunMP I edited my post. It now shows LoadingScreen class and what is passed over to the LocationScreen(Main Screen).. it basically uses another class called NetworkHelper to get data from API and passes it over to LocationScreen.

Comment: @Polyamorous Please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are passing a Future instead of actual data. The getData method returns a future, you need to await for the result.

```
var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
```

Comment: Great! That works. I only missed await, updateUI function also doesn't need to be asynchronous. Thank you.